# How to refresh the Schema browser in toad?

Tags: toad

This link give a answer to this question.
https://forums.toadworld.com/t/refresh-schemas/26455

But I don't find what match this description:

> There are 3 buttons on the SB’s toolbar with circular arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about these 3 buttons in the Schema Browser window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the keyboard shortcuts F5 refresh the Schema Browser.